# DataGridView row color is not changed when the same form is opened again

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to make a simple inventory system that is displayed from a data bounded DataGridView. I want to change the row color of a specific item if an item is less than the minimum required limit.

When I open the form with the DatagridView, the row colors of each item is successfully changed to red if it is less than the minimum amount. However when I close the form and open it again, the row color is not changed.

I try to replace the text of a column if the stock is below the requirement to check if the function is working and it did change the text of the cell even if I open and close the form but not the row color of the affected rows.
I have tried manually loading the rows into the DataGridView and not using the `SqlDataAdapter`
and the DataGridView and it works perfectly fine even if I open and close the form again.

But I want to take advantage of the `SqlDataAdapter.Update()` function where I create, update and delete items in the DataGridView itself when the update button is clicked.
Here is my code:

So my question is why do the DataGridView custom row colors are not changed even when the same form is opened again?

```
    Dim dataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim commandBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim dataSet As DataSet

    Private Sub Inventory_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM Inventory"
            dataSet = New DataSet

            dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(query, SQLCon)
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)

            DGVInventory.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)

            'Change the row color of insufficient item quantity
            For row As Integer = 0 To DGVInventory.Rows.Count - 1
                If DGVInventory.Rows(row).Cells(2).Value < DGVInventory.Rows(row).Cells(3).Value Then
                    DGVInventory.Rows(row).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
                    DGVInventory.Rows(row).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Inventory_Load() Function Error")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnSaveChanges_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSaveChanges.Click
        Try
            commandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter)
            dataAdapter.Update(dataSet, "Inventory")
            MessageBox.Show("Database has been updated.", "Update Successful!")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "BtnSaveChanges_Click() Function Error")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Check when you close the form, do you have disposed every thing? check Inventory_Load, does it work when you open form again?

Comment: The DataGridView shows all the data from my database every time I open it up but the color of the row is not changed the second time I open it. I don't have an idea if it disposed every thing as I don't have an event handler yet for FormClosing.

Comment: try me.dispose when close

Comment: I suppose the Inventory_Load event did't run for the second and next form open

Comment: `Options Strict On` ;)

Comment: Are you using the `default instance` of the form, or are you instantiating the form explicitly?

Comment: I only used the default instance I guess? I use ```Form1.ShowDialog()``` to call this form. The ```Me.Dispose()``` upon FormClosing event works fine but is there any other way to solve this problem? Other solutions will be appreciated.